# ¿Cómo saber el peso total de un directorio con subcarpetas y archivos en PHP (Framework LARAVEL)?

Tags: php, laravel

Necesito **calcular el peso total de un directorio cuyo contenido son otras subcarpetas con archivos, simulando visualizar el "propiedades" de windows** para obtener su peso total.

Cualquiera de éstas unidades me servirían KB, MB o GB.

Actualmente calculo el número de directorios y archivos de ésta manera:

```
Storage::disk('public_dir')->allDirectories($ruta_del_directorio)
Storage::disk('public_dir')->allFiles($ruta_del_directorio);
```

Me preguntaba si existe alguna **manera similar** de obtener el peso total del directorio.

Comment: Si no lo quieres en MB o GB entonces en que medida los buscas?

Comment: Mencioné que no me interesa por ahora obtener alguna en espécifica, tal ves generé mal mi pregunta. en cualquier medida de las tres me sirven

Comment: Ya he corregido mi pregunta para evitar confusiones, una disculpa. Cualquiera de estas tres medidas me servirían para mi problema

Comment: Intenta con esta estructura `$size = Storage::size('file.jpg');`

Comment: igualmente encontre esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505894/laravel-5-get-size-from-all-files-inside-a-directory

Comment: He logrado solucionar mi problema, he anexado mi respuesta. Me ha servido tu respuesta para obtener el valor individual de cada archivo, por mi parte fue sumarlas, convertir bytes a MB y solo obtener los dos primeros decimales. Gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 1):

He resuelto mi problema de la siguiente manera:

- Obteniendo el peso de cada archivo almacenándolos en un array.
- Se suman todas las posiciones del array para obtener un total.
- El resultado es en bytes, por lo tanto se divide entre 1,048,576 (obtención en MB).
- Utilizo el round de PHP para obtener solo dos decimales.

De manera práctica les comparto el código:

```
$directorio="Aqui_va_la ubicacion_de_su_directorio";
$sizeArray= array(); //Arreglo donde se almacenarán los archivos para posteriormente sumarlas
//Se obtienen todos los archivos   
$archivos_array = Storage::disk('public_dir')->allFiles($directorio); 
//Se calcula el peso de cada archivo con una iteración almacenándolo en el array
      foreach ($archivos_array as $key => $file) {
        $sizeArray[$key]=Storage::disk('public_dir')->size($file);
      }
//Se procene a crear una suma de todo el array, convertirla a megas y solo obtener los dos decimales
$totalSize=round((array_sum($files_with_size))/1048576, 2);
```